Creating Nav Menu with SubNav Gatsby and React
I am currently able to generate a Nav menu however I would like to now add submenu items under each main nav item. I am using Gatsby with React. I have the following array:
const items = [
  {
    to: "/solutions",
    content: "Solutions",
    subMenu: [
      {
        to: "/pharmacies",
        content:"Pharmacy",
      },
      {
        to: "/pharmacies",
        content:"Provider",
      },
      {
        to: "/payors",
        content:"Payors",
      },
      {
        to: "/pharma",
        content:"Pharma",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    to: "/howitworks",
    content: "How It Works",
  },
  {
    to: "/resources",
    content: "Resources",
  },
  {
    to: "/aboutus",
    content: "About Us",
  }

];


And then my code to grab items from the array is:
return (
    <div
      className={`
      clear-both
      font-semibold uppercase
      flex
      flex-col lg:flex-row
      items-center
      sm:items-end lg:items-center
      ${className}
      `}
    >
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div>
           <Link key={`navbar-${item.to}`} className={classNames} to={item.to}>
            {item.content}
           </Link>
         </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

As I said I get the main nav items (Solutions, How it Works, etc) but I am not sure how to get the submenu items. Any help is appreciated.
I have looked around and have found plenty of example using map to access the first level of the array but struggling to find the right example that explains grabbing nested or child nodes.

Using recursion is a good way to handle nested submenus.
here’s an example, You just need to manage the styles.
import React from 'react'

export type Item = {
    to: string
    content: string
    subMenu?: Item[]
}

const items: Item[] = [
    {
        to: '/solutions',
        content: 'Solutions',
        subMenu: [
            {
                to: '/pharmacies',
                content: 'Pharmacy',
            },
            {
                to: '/pharmacies',
                content: 'Provider',
            },
            {
                to: '/payors',
                content: 'Payors',
            },
            {
                to: '/pharma',
                content: 'Pharma',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        to: '/howitworks',
        content: 'How It Works',
    },
    {
        to: '/resources',
        content: 'Resources',
    },
    {
        to: '/aboutus',
        content: 'About Us',
    },
]

const Menu = ({ items }: { items: Item[] }) => {
    return (
        <div className="menu">
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="menu-item">
                    <a href={item.to}>{item.content}</a>
                    {item.subMenu && (
                        <div className="submenu">
                            <Menu items={item.subMenu} />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const Test = () => {
    return <Menu items={items} />
}

export default Test

